# Deleted home directory files, how to change bash prompt

Tags: scientific-linux

I was playing around on Scientific Linux 7 and deleted all the files from my home directory. Now the bash prompt is `bash-4.2$`. How can I change the prompt and save it. I edited the `/etc/bashrc` but changing the `$PS1` does not change the prompt.

Comment: did you re-login or sourced your `/etc/bashrc` ?

Comment: How did you change `PS1`?

Comment: anyway, it is better to update your `~/.bashrc` then the global.

Comment: I have re-logged in, I don't know what you mean by sourcing the `/etc/bashrc/`

Comment: I set `PS1` to "$" in `/etc/bashrc`, I don't think that is where it is supposed to be set

Comment: What @Jakuje meant by "sourcing" `/etc/bashrc` is literally if you run `source /etc/bashrc` in your current session. And I agree with him when saying that you better update (or rewrite, in your case) your `~/.bashrc`, since changes in `/etc/bashrc` affect all users in the system, and changes in `~/.bashrc` affect only your user. Could you show the exact contents of `PS1` variable?

Comment: If I run `echo $PS1` then I get `\s-\v$`. I don't know where that is being set.

Comment: If you blew away your home directory, you might want to copy all the stuff in `/etc/skel` to your home directory -- that'd, in general, be what you started out with originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy everything from `/etc/skel/` to your home and change the owner to yourself.

There should be a `.bashrc` in it.